# Make [facebook-stories] a synonym of [facebook-stream-story]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I think tag name [facebook-stream-story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-stream-story) is a bit confusing, because it will not pop up in the tag suggestions if you type `"story"` or `"facebook-sto"`. I did not know this tag exists and stumbled upon it accidentally. I think that's why many people just tag their questions with ambiguous [story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/story) tag.

I think these synonyms would be helpful:

- [facebook-story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-story) -> [facebook-stream-story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-stream-story)
- [facebook-stories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-stories) -> [facebook-stream-story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-stream-story)

This may prevent confusion with [user-stories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-stories) and [story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/story).
I can't propose a synonym because I have not enough reputation for [facebook-stream-story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-stream-story).

P.S. It would be great if we can make [facebook-stories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-stories) a main tag, and [facebook-stream-story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-stream-story) a synonym (vice versa).

Comment: This just reminded me, I was thinking there should be some kind of notification system for those following that tag, for when a tag synonym is suggested.